# Algunos elementos en mi listview se muestran vacios xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Buen día, estoy rellenando un listview con datos que provienen de un webservices, la lista se rellena pero solo muestra el texto bindeado de los primeros 13 con su texto y un icono que es estatico, y los demas items se muestran pero estan vacios, sin icono sin texto sin embargo si muestra el espacio vacios del viewcell (en total son 52). No se que estoy haciendo mal, cabe destacar que todos los 52 registros traen bien su texto que deben mostrar. les dejo el codigo que estoy implementando.

Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
   x:Class="R.Confiable.Companies"
   BackgroundColor="#f1f2f2">
   <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
       <ToolbarItem Icon="setting" Clicked="PopUpMenu"></ToolbarItem>
   </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
   <ContentPage.Content>
       <StackLayout>
           <ListView x:Name="listViewItem" HasUnevenRows="true" SeparatorColor="Transparent" ItemSelected="chooseFolio">
               <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <ViewCell>
                           <Fra me CornerRadius="7" Padding="0" Margin="8">
                               <StackLayout Padding="8,16" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                   <Fra me HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24" HasShadow="false" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="0" CornerRadius="24" BackgroundColor="#fd6500">
                                       <Image Source="shop" WidthRequest="24" HeightRequest="24" Margin="10"></Image>
                                   </Frame>
                                   <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                       <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding company}"></Label>
                                   </StackLayout>
                               </StackLayout>
                           </Frame>
                       </ViewCell>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </ListView.ItemTemplate>
           </ListView>
       </StackLayout>
   </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Código C#

```
public async void RequestServerData()
        {

           await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new LoadingPage());

           try
           {
               ObservableCollection<CompanyModelFormat> companies = new ObservableCollection<CompanyModelFormat>();

               await Task.Run(() =>
               {
                   //Mobile
                   var response = (new RpcClient()).GetDataResult("get_company_system_mobile_by_id_user", "TRACKING");


                   for (int x = 0; x < response.Data.Count; x++)
                   {
                       companies.Add(new CompanyModelFormat
                       {
                           company = response.Data[x][1]
                       });
                       Console.WriteLine(response.Data[x][1]);
                   }

                   Console.WriteLine("*********************");
                   Console.WriteLine(response.Data.Count);

               });
               Console.WriteLine(companies.Count);

               listViewItem.ItemsSource = companies;

           }
           catch (RCException ex)
           {



           }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontré la solución es un problema de memoria, al ser muchos items al parecer no puede mostrarlos todos así que era necesario hacer que los items en la lista se reciclen, dejo este enlace por si alguien tiene este mismo problema ahí verán sobre el reciclado de los items.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance#cachingstrategy